# Rolling function with conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

The objective is to calculate the Cum.Buy variable that is rolling sum of the Buy.Volume for all rows where the Volume.Cumsum is up to 10000 lass than the current value. For example, for Row 622, Cum.Buy will sum the Buy.Volume of the current Row (6000) and the Buy.Volume of all Rows where the Volume.Cumsum is between 9973 and (9973-10000=-27), which includes Row 566. Do, Cum.Buy equals 6000+2718. Secondly, using the same parameters I was looking to get the initial price.

```
df <- read.table(text="
Row Price Volume Volume.Cumsum Buy.Volume
550 6.249    151           151          0
554 6.249   1104          1255          0
566 6.250   2718          3973       2718
622 6.250   6000          9973       6000
652 6.249    745         10718          0
653 6.249   1292         12010          0
661 6.250   5918         17928       5918
663 6.250  13130         31058      13130
664 6.250   4894         35952       4894
673 6.250   4894         40846       4894", header=T)
```

I have tried the function, but am getting a binary operator error:

```
BV <- function(x) {
  if (is.null(dim(x))) x <- t(x)
  tt <- x[, "Volume.Cumsum"]
  sum(x[tt >= tail(tt, 1) - 10000, "Buy.Volume"])
}

df = transform(df,Cum.Buy=rollapplyr(df,100,BV,by.column=FALSE,partial=TRUE)
```

The resulting output should look like:

```
df <- read.table(text="
Row Price Volume Volume.Cumsum Buy.Volume   Cum.Buy   Price.Lag
550 6.249    151           151          0         0       6.249
554 6.249   1104          1255          0         0       6.249
566 6.250   2718          3973       2718      2718       6.249
622 6.250   6000          9973       6000      8718       6.249
652 6.249    745         10718          0      8718       6.249
653 6.249   1292         12010          0      8718       6.250
661 6.250   5918         17928       5918     11918       6.250
663 6.251  13130         31058      13130     13130       6.251
664 6.250   4894         35952       4894     18024       6.251
673 6.250   4894         40846       4894     22918       6.251", header=T)
```

Comment: What is `Data` in the `rollapplyr` call?  I guess you need `df` instead of 'Data' i.e. `transform(df,Cum.Buy=rollapplyr(df,100,BV,by.column=FALSE,partial=TRUE))`

Comment: Yes, thats correct. Edited now.

Comment: Not sure about the conditions about calculating 'Price.Lag'

Comment: So, same as volume. If the Volume.Cumsum is in a range of 10,000, then return the first Price of that series.